# What does return alone do in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def process_blog(blogid):
    blog = get_blog(blogid)
    if blog == None:
        return
    else:
        return blog
```

What does this return in the 4th line do?. What does it returns when blog == None.?

Comment: Well when `blog` is not `None`, they `return` its actual value, but if `blog` is `None`, and you want to `return` the value of `blog`, you want to `return None`. That's exactly what an empty `return` statement does.

Comment: @nidhinpd, You might as well just have `return blog` after `blog = get_blog(blogid)` since in either case you will be returning `None` if blog does not exist.

Comment: Actually this isn't the real code. I cut down the intermediate part since it is not necessary for this discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bare `return` (or no `return` at all at the end of the function) is equal to `return None`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def a():
...     return None
...
>>> def b():
...     return
...
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

FYI, you should use `is None` to check against `None´ instead of`== None`. However, in your case the whole function can be simplified to this (which makes it somewhat pointless):

```
def process_blog(blogid):
    return get_blog(blogid)
```

Comment: I just simplified the actual function for the sake of simplicity. :)